# PhpStorm Xdebug Frames and variables are not available

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I installed PhpStorm and Xdebug. When I'm trying to debug in a PhpStorm, not on a web page the debugger doesn't work.

I added the following code in php.ini

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.8.0-7.2-vc15.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
```

I also downloaded "php_xdebug-2.8.0-7.2-vc15.dll" and put it in `C:\xampp\php\ext` folder.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you restarted Apache after installing Xdebug? is it enabled and configured correctly there? (check `phpinfo()` output captured via browser). **P.S.** For CLI debug (PHP Script type of Run/Debug configuration) PhpStorm will pass all needed parameters via command line. For web debug you need to configure it all yourself (as IDE cannot configure your web server for you). https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html

Comment: Hi, yes I restarted. In phpinfo() file it says that I have xdebug

Comment: Try Xdebug 2.7.x perhaps (have not tried 2.8 myself yet). And try some more simple code, I'm not super sure if IDE works great with dynamic user input via `redline()` (e.g. try like this, one instruction per line: `<?php $a = 1; $b = 3; $c = $a + $b; echo $c;`). Make sure no symlinks in the script path. If still nothing -- configure Xdebug to collect logs and see what it shows there for such unsuccessful debug session.

Comment: Hi, I tried as you said and hard code the input and it is working. I was with Xdebug 2.6/2.7 and it was the same. Curious why it's not working with readline(). I had an older laptop with the same configurations and it's working without a problem. How I can check the path for symlinks?

Comment: *"How I can check the path for symlinks?*" Check what file xdebug log reports and compare it to your path. If it's different then you may have a symlink or junction point somewhere in the path. But then -- IDE should be telling you that no path is mapped or stuff like that (unless you have disabled such notifications or whatnot).

Comment: Nothing still the same problem. I don't know what to do.

Comment: I see that: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-50124. I have no clue if it's PhpStorm or Xdebug issue

Comment: I am using the same settings on my old laptop (Toshiba) and everything is working great. Now I have Dell. I know that this can not be a reason but just saying. It is really annoying.